# Store user-generated HTML form and related submissions

Tags: javascript, json, database, drag-and-drop, nosql

Primarily for educational purposes, I want to build a **form builder** (basically like google forms or form.io).

Therefore the frontend (React) should enable the user to generate an HTML form using drag and drop. Submissions to this specific form should be validated against the form.
The backend will be exposed via a REST API.

**The question is:** How should I store the user-generated HTML form and validate submissions against the form.

My initial plan was storing a JSON-like representation of the form in a NoSQL DB like AWS Dynamodb and validate a submission against that schema.